# Dropdown with 'labels' in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is it a way to get a dropdown with 'labels' in Google Sheet?
I have a range with 2 fields - ID and Name. I would like to choose Name in the dropdown and the ID should be inserted. Is it possible?
Here is the test spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_yZ5EFDcU3yX_e61_iP2QYff-ifrKhK_2PesxzmxJQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 4):

try this trick:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, {B2:B, A2:A}, 2, 0)
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZMvdP2ZF4OZAn2sxHEMqWMw3JNBLoSMe4w5ugBmWkk/copy)