VLOOKUP help - Specific column search returns okay but multiple column says it does not exist
If I do this formula, it can find the value I want:
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet Name'!E2:E,1,FALSE)

However, if I do this formula, it says the same value returned from above does not exist in the search criteria:
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet Name'!A2:E,2,FALSE)

I'm trying to find the value from column A in a range of another sheet so that I get a specific column from that sheet, it would be in column B of that other sheet. But it doesn't find the A2 in the E column like it did on the previous formula.
This is the error it triggers on that second formula: Did not find value 'value in A2' in VLOOKUP evaluation.
I'm completely lost.

Are you using Excel or Google Sheets this is because Excel doesn't supports open ended reference based on your formula: =VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet Name'!A2:E,2,FALSE)

VLOOKUP expects the value to be in the leftmost column. If the lookup reference in 'Sheet Name'!A2:E, then VLOOKUP won't find a value in column E.

Apologies. I tagged Excel but that was completely wrong, it's definitely from Sheets.
As for BigBen's comment, yeah, I guess the keyword "first" didn't exactly write into my brain it meant first column available in the search.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69771051/5632629


You may try:
=VLOOKUP(A2,{'Sheet Name'!E:E,'Sheet Name'!B:B},2,FALSE)

OR to save the confusion with vlookup index number, go with xlookup
=xlookup(A2,'Sheet Name'!E:E,'Sheet Name'!B:B,)


Thank you! Very interesting way to do multiple searches in VLOOKUP. I've tried with XLOOKUP and it worked. Completely forgot about it.

If you look at the official documentation for VLOOKUP, you see this:

Syntax
=VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
Inputs

search_key: The value to search for in the first column of the range.


Since in your modified range argument A2:E column E is no longer the first column, your lookup fails.
You can use the XLOOKUP function, which has this syntax:
XLOOKUP(search_key, lookup_range, result_range, missing_value, match_mode, search_mode)
As you can see, the lookup and result ranges are split parameters. This allows you to perform the lookup in column E but pick the result from column A for example.
Note that neither VLOOKUP nor XLOOKUP support a lookup in more than a single column.

This makes a lot of sense. I forgot about XLOOKUP. Failed to realized the keyword "first" in VLOOKUP.
This did solve my initial mess. I wrote on another cell with XLOOKUP and worked like a charm.
Thank you!

Found a different formula to get what I wanted. Might help others in the future with different solutions:
=INDEX('Sheet Name'!$B$2:B,MATCH(A2,'Sheet Name'!$E$2:E,0))

